# Combobox displays correctly only locally

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

i have a serious problem.

I have a combobox in a webform. everything works fine locally. When the project is published i can't click on the combobox to display the various items. It more or less looks like a basic textbox....

This is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style id="Style1" type="text/css" runat="server">
        td
        {
            vertical-align: top;
        }
        input.RadUploadSubmit
        {
            margin-top: 20px;
        }

        #RadUpload1
        {
            width: 355px;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function CloseWindow() {
            var oManager = GetRadWindowManager();
            var oWnd = oManager.GetWindowByName("RadWindow1");
            oWnd.Close();

        }

        function GetRadWindow() {
            var oWindow = null;
            if (window.radWindow) oWindow = window.radWindow;
            else if (window.frameElement.radWindow) oWindow = window.frameElement.radWindow;
            return oWindow;
        }

        function CloseDialog() {
            GetRadWindow().close();
            return true;


        }  

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form runat="server" id="Form1">
    <%--method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"--%>
    <div id="formulaire">
        <center>
            Ticket : <b>
                <asp:Label ID="TicketFamille" runat="server"></asp:Label></b></center>
                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblERROR" Visible="false"></asp:Label>
        <table cellpadding="5px" cellspacing="2px">
            <tr>
                <td width="200px" align='right'>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblTitre" runat="server" Text="Titre"></asp:Label>
                    &nbsp;:
                </td>
                <td>
                    <telerik:RadTextBox ID="txtTitre" runat="server" Skin="Telerik" Width="250">
                    </telerik:RadTextBox>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="*"
                        ForeColor="Red" ControlToValidate="txtTitre" ValidationGroup="validationincident"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align='right'>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblCategorie" runat="server" Text="Concerne : "></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true"
                        OnSelectedIndexChanged="RadioButtonList1_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true">
                        <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="1">Projet</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="2">Sous-categorie</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:RadioButtonList>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align='right'>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblSousCategorie" runat="server" Text="Sous Categorie :"></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <telerik:RadComboBox ID="cbSousCategorie" runat="server" Skin="Telerik">
                    </telerik:RadComboBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align='right'>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblProjet" runat="server" Text="Projet : "></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <telerik:RadComboBox ID="cbProjet" runat="server" DataTextField="nomProjet" DataValueField="idProjet"
                        Skin="Telerik">
                    </telerik:RadComboBox>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" ErrorMessage="*"
                        ForeColor="Red" ControlToValidate="cbProjet" ValidationGroup="validationincident"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align='right'>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblDescription" runat="server" Text="Description : "></asp:Label>

                </td>
                <td>
                    <telerik:RadTextBox ID="txtDescription" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Width="250"
                        Height="100" Skin="Telerik">
                    </telerik:RadTextBox>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator3" runat="server" ErrorMessage="*"
                        ForeColor="Red" ControlToValidate="txtDescription" ValidationGroup="validationincident"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align='right'>
                    Joindre un fichier :
                </td>
                <td>
                    <br />
                    <telerik:RadUpload ID="RadUpload1" runat="server" MaxFileInputsCount="5" Skin="Telerik">
                        <Localization Add="Ajouter" Clear="Vider" Delete="Supprimer" Select="Parcourir" />
                    </telerik:RadUpload>
                    <br />
                    <asp:Repeater ID="reportResults" runat="server" Visible="False">
                        <HeaderTemplate>
                            Fichiers attachés:<br />
                        </HeaderTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            '<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "FileName")%>' ( '<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ContentLength").ToString() + " bytes"%>'
                            )<br />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:Repeater>
                    <%--<asp:Button ID="buttonSubmit" CssClass="RadUploadSubmit" OnClick="buttonSubmit_Click"
        runat="server" Text="Joindre le fichier" />--%>
                    <br />
                    <%--<asp:Label ID="labelNoResults" runat="server" Visible="True">Pas de fichier joint pour le moment</asp:Label>--%>
                    <br />
                </td>
            </tr>
            </table>
        <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="HiddenFieldIdContact" />
                    <center><asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Soumettre ce ticket" OnClick="Button1_Click"
                        OnClientClick="if(Page_ClientValidate()) CloseDialog()" UseSubmitBehavior="false"
                        ValidationGroup="validationincident" /></center>
    </div>
    <center>
        <telerik:RadScriptManager ID="RadScriptManager1" Runat="server">
        </telerik:RadScriptManager>
    </center>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks again for your help !!!

Comment: Is Telerik installed on the server you are publishing to?

Comment: You are at the mercy of Telerik.  You may need to consult their help files.

Comment: Use firebug or other tool to make sure that css styles have been applied to the controls.

Comment: As Andrei has said, check it with Firebug, you might need to modify the z-index of some elements: the ddl might be behind a div or something.

Comment: @ArnaudAdigard If you email me a sample project that demonstrates the problem I would be happy to take a look at it.  Or, can you send me the URL where you are publishing to that has the issue?  That would be easier.

Comment: where is the code to bind combobox with datasource?

Answer (score 2):

Have all the required DLL's or in your website BIN folder?

I think we have the same scenario, But I used Devexpress. 
I don't know if is a bug on VS studio, but I have to manually add all the DLL's I used on my project BIN folder and upload it to production server.

Hope this help you!

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that you have hit one of the famous ( won't fix :) ) IE limitations - 31 stylesheets per page and 4095 selectors per file. 
http://blogs.telerik.com/aspnetmvcteam/posts/10-05-03/internet-explorer-css-limits.aspx

I'd recommend that you see if the problem exists in FF or Chrome.

Here you can find a test page, demonstrating the problem in IE.
http://demos.telerik.com/testcases/BrokenTheme.aspx

In the first case, you can try to combine the files as explained here:
http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/general-discussions/custom-skin-asp-net-theme-ie-31-style-sheet-limit.aspx

This is just an assumption of course :) Normally, it is not easy to guess what happens in such scenario.

Answer (score 1):

If your combo box works in dev, but not in production (or other environment), I think your problem is the data source.

you can confirm this by hardcoding the values for the combo box and seeing if it is then clickable in production.

Answer (score 0):

Hello Dear Arnaud Adigard, if you code works fine locally then there show be a server problem where you are trying to deploy it. May be some file is missing or any other problem. It's generally not your cade problem because it's fine. :)

Answer (score 0):

Check web config and make sure debug mode is False once it is deploy to IIS.

```html
<compilation debug="false" strict="false" explicit="true">
   <assemblies>
   </assemblies>
</compilation>
```